# log4j: log multiple exceptions at once?

Tags: java, log4j

I have some code like the following:

```
List<Exception> exceptions = new ArrayList<Exception>();
for (Foo foo : foos) {
     try {
        doStuff(foo);
     } catch (FooException ex) {
        exceptions.add(ex);
     }
}
if (!exceptions.isEmpty())
   logger.error("Exceptions occurred processing foos", exceptions);
```

and in my log, I would see the full details about each exception, including the stack trace, cause chain and so on. This code doesn't actually work, of course. Is there a way to get it so a single log entry contains all of them?

As for why not just log each exception as it's caught, the reason is that I am using `SMTPAppender` and would rather get just one email about this.

Comment: How about [Filtering lines in your log file with ERROR](http://rerun.me/2012/08/30/filter-lines-in-log-file-with-error/)?

Comment: You could try creating a custom Exception class that encapsulates your list of Exceptions.

Comment: @SandeepChatterjee that isn't really relevant to my question. I understand how to read log files. But in my question, I'm having log entries emailed automatically so I'm trying to find a way to consolidate them.

Comment: @EvanLaHurd that's a thought. So would I just have to make that exception's "message" the combined stack traces of all of the others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easy & clean way:

#### 1. Create your own Exception like:

```java
class CompositeException extends Exception {
    private final List<Exception> es;

    public CompositeException(Exception[] es) {
        this.es = Arrays.asList(es);
    }

    public CompositeException(List<Exception> es) {
        this.es = new ArrayList<Exception>(es);
    }

    @Override
    public void printStackTrace(PrintStream s) {
        for (Throwable e : this.es) {
            e.printStackTrace(s);
        }
    }
}
```

#### 2. Then use the CompositeException class:

```java
List<Exception> exceptions = new ArrayList<Exception>();
for (Foo foo : foos) {
    try {
        doStuff(foo);
    } catch (FooException ex) {
        exceptions.add(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 This is a much more well-constructed example than mine! Although you should add the type parameter to `private final List es;`

Answer (score 1):

I've been messing around with it, and I was able to just combine the stack traces of each Exception in your list to be passed into a new custom Exception:

```
public class MyException extends Exception {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MyException {

        StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();

        List<Exception> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                divideByZero(i);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
            }
        }

        if (!errors.toString().isEmpty()) {
            throw new MyException(errors.toString());
        }
    }

    public MyException(String message) {
        super (message);
    }

    public static int divideByZero(int i) {
       return i/0;
    }
}
```

This is a pretty contrived example, but I just wanted to convey the idea I had...you could tweak/improve it to include more information if you wanted.

This printed the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" MyException: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at MyException.divideByZero(MyException.java:34)
    at MyException.main(MyException.java:24)
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at MyException.divideByZero(MyException.java:34)
    at MyException.main(MyException.java:24)
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at MyException.divideByZero(MyException.java:34)
    at MyException.main(MyException.java:24)

    at MyException.main(MyException.java:30)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the stack traces for the exceptions, you could iterate over the list and call the getMessage (or getLocalisedMessage) method in the log statement for each exception. That should print out the type of the exception as well as the cause.